# Markdown to online blog/wiki/guides?

Tags: markdown

Are there sites where I can have an account, type in my markdown and then it would generate pretty blog/wiki/guides for me automatically without me having to bother with setting up a server and so on?

Comment: You might try putting this on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of do this with [hashify.me](http://hashify.me) as long as your text isn't too long